# Render variable shows [object Object] instead of its value

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Using AlpineJS I am submitting a form and displaying error messages when the API return an error:

```
  <form x-data="inquiry()" x-on:submit.prevent="submit" method="post">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" x-model="data.name.value">
    <span x-show="data.name.error !== null" x-text="data.name.error"></span>

    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" x-model="data.email.value">
    <span x-show="data.email.error !== null" x-text="data.email.error"></span>

    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function inquiry() {

      return {

        data: {
          name: { value: "", error: null },
          email: { value: "", error: null }
        },

        submit() {

          fetch("/inquiries", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              name: this.data.name.value,
              email: this.data.email.value
          })

          .then((response) => {

            if (response.ok) {

            } else {

              response.json().then((body) => {

                for (const key in this.data) 
                  this.data[key].error = body.errors.find(x => x.source.toLowerCase() == key.toLowerCase()) ?? null;

              });
            }
          })
        }
      };
    }
  </script>
```

When I submit the form with errors I get the response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    { "source": "Email", "detail": "The email is invalid" },
    { "source": "Name", "detail": "The name is required" },
  ]
}
```

But, for example, the `span` that would show the error detail for `name` renders:

```
[object Object]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(<some object>)`  to produce a printable string

Comment: What does this `body.errors.find(x => x.source.toLowerCase() == key.toLowerCase()) ?? null` return?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski for each error im the response gets ithe value of source property and then finds the property in data with the same name and signs the value of error property to the value of detail property if the json

Comment: I just guess it returns an object instead of a string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like This:

```js
var resp = {
  "errors": [
    { "source": "Email", "detail": "The email is invalid" },
    { "source": "Name", "detail": "The name is required" }
  ]
};
if(resp['errors']){ //if error exist in response
     alert('ERRORS: \n\n' + JSON.stringify(resp['errors'], null, 4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value of `data[key].error` to the found object row from your body, not to the error *inside* the object.

This will fix it:

```js
for (const key in data) {
    this.data[key].error = body.errors.find(x => x.source.toLowerCase() == key.toLowerCase())?.detail ?? null;
}
```

I'm using `?.` ([optional chainig](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) as the object row might not exist, but if it does, we fetch the `detail` value from the row. In the case it's `undefined`, or `detail` doesn't exist, it will default to `null`.